# MAUI Loading of the "observablecollection" type object slower and slower when refreshing data from the database

Tags: maui

I have this problem:

I am using an object CLItemsList of type observablecollection.

Every time before loading data into it, I clean it:

```
CLItemsList.Clear();
```

Next
I am fetching data from the database:

```
 SqlCommand command = new(selectQuery, connection);

            SqlDataReader result = command.ExecuteReader();

            if (result.HasRows)
            {
                while (result.Read())
                {
                    CLItemsList.Add(new ModCLRec
                    {
                        // Lp = result.GetInt32(result.GetOrdinal("LP")),
                        Lp = NrLp++,
                        ID = result.GetInt32(result.GetOrdinal("ID")),
            ...
                        ColorBg = NrLp % 2 == 1 ? ModAppParams.ColorOrange1 : ModAppParams.ColorOrange2
                    });
                }
                RecordListView.ItemsSource = null;
                RecordListView.ItemsSource = CLItemsList;
```

When I read the data again in this way, it is slower and slower until the process is almost completely suspended.

What am I doing wrong ?

Please help and thank you!

I have no idea for a solution :(

Comment: If you are clearing and reloading the entire dataset each time then there is not much point in using an ObservableCollection.  But you really need to do more work to narrow down the source of the problem.  Is the query itself slower?  The loop?  Are you processing the same amount of data each time?  Do you really need to load the entire dataset each time?

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Unfortunately, a different set of data is loaded each time. They differ in the number of lines and content. Data reading is fast (less than 3ms). But creating objects and loading data into them takes more and more time.

Comment: Don’t use an ObservableCollection

Comment: I changed to regular List and now it's OK. Thanks :)

Comment: For future reference, an alternative way to fix it is to load items into a DIFFERENT collection each time. The slowness happened because ObservableCollection redraws the display over and over, as you add items. (Its designed for cases where you add/remove one or a few items.) `var newList = new ObservableCollection<MyTypeHere>(); ...add items to newList... CLItemsList = newList; RecordListView.ItemsSource = newList;` No reason to do this, unless later you will add/remove items one at a time.

Answer (score 0):

**Summary**

Due to the object CLItemsList of type `Observablecollection`. When you are fetching data from the database then it will update the data instantly. So this is the reason why when you update a lot of data to the CLItemsList it will be slower and slower until the process is almost completely suspended.

**Solution**

You can change the `Observablecollection` to the `List`.